# Anonymous Users SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, anonymous-authentication, external-users

A user has reported a concern that 'Anonymous Users' is visible at the site collection level.
I don't know why its visible or how it has happened. First I thought it could be related top external sharing / external link sharing but cannot find much info why it would say 'Entire Web Site'. Is it a legacy permission when MS used to allow Anonymous Site Access back in 2017?
[image: Anonymous Users]

I've also noticed something that could be related -In a subsite a strange Limited Access entry - I'm used to seeing Limited access, but why Sharing Links with a Guid...?
[image: Limited Access]

Answer (score 0):

Are you working with SharePoint Online? As far as I know, Anonymous access has been discontinued for SharePoint online. Please take a reference to this article: [SharePoint Online Public Websites to be discontinued](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/sharepoint/troubleshoot/sites/public-websites-be-discontinued). If this phenomenon still exists, I suggest you to New service request from Microsoft 365 admin center.